# Record RTMFP in Flash Media Server 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash-media-server, rtmfp

how are you? I'm developing an online meeting system with audio/video sharing, using Adobe Flex 4 and Flash Media Server 4. I'm using the RTMFP protocol to make the transmission of audio/video which increases considerably the performance. The trouble now is that i must record the audio/video transmitted, but i figured out that when using the RTMFP protocol the FMS doesn't operate in the channels. So, how could i make FMS record this channels?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

FMS cannot record it. You can either record it in the client side, or send the data backwards to your server and record it there.

Comment: Record in the client wouldn't be a nice solution to my case, but we changed to LCCS components because they are offering this feature. Thanks for your answer.